# Activity slide animation only works when back button is pressed

Tags: android, animation, overridependingtransition

Im trying to add a sliding animation when entering and exiting an activity but it only works when the phones back button is pressed. When pressing the up button in the toolbar or a separate button it doesn't work.

I tried adding the `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.no_anim, R.anim.slide_out_right);` line to the `onPause()` method as well as the `finish()` method and the buttons OnClick method but it doesn't work :/

no_anim.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="0"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="0" />
</set>
```

slide_out_right.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="100%p" />
</set>
```

Java:

```
public void button(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.no_anim, R.anim.slide_out_right);
}

@Override
public void finish(){
    super.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.no_anim, R.anim.slide_out_right);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.no_anim, R.anim.slide_out_right);
}
```

Comment: Use `toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener();` as suggested in my answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can call `onBackPressed()` when pressing the up button in the toolbar

Comment: This is not regarded as a good approach! `onBackPressed()` should be called when we want to handle default back button clicks in android! If android wished to do so, why they would have added the facility to provide back click facility on toolbar with its `toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener()`?

Answer (score 1):

Set toolbar Navigation click listener:

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        finish(); //close activity
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.your_anim, R.anim.your_anim);
    }
});
```

This will surely work!